# ccminer hashing speed not onpar with minergate-gui

Tags: hashrate

I have NVIDIA-TESLA-K40, I was using MinerGate v6.6 GUI version -Hash speed of 290KH/S. where as ccminer only giving 120 H/S. lot of difference, from Kilo hash/sec to hash/sec. How to optimally use TESLA K40

Answer (score 1):

i experienced similar Hashrates with MinerGate v6.6.
After updating to 6.7 the Hashrates were more accurate compard to them from ccminer.

From my perspective it was a wrong hashrate which was displayed.
You didn't name your operating system, but you could do a double check hashrates using linux ccminer vs windows ccminer.

Best regards